# How to retrieve a property of an object from a string?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

In order to use it as a selector in a Grouping Clause at runtime, I want basically retrieve a property from an object T by passing its name. Example with this class:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use my method like this:

```
private void MyMethod(string propertyName)
{
    var lambda = GetLambdaExpression(propertyName);

    // The problem is to specify the Type at compile time...
    var selector = GetLambdaSelector<DateTime>(lambda); // Seems mandatory to convert LambdaExpression to Expression<Func<Person, T>> to use in a grouping clause
    
    var result = emps.GroupBy(
        selector.Compile(),
        p => p.Birthday,
        (key, g) => new { PersonName = key, = g.ToList() }).AsQueryable();
}
```

Here are methods statements :

```
        LambdaExpression GetLambdaExpression(string propertyName)
        {
            var type = typeof(Person); 

            var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

            var entityType = propertyInfo.DeclaringType;
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
            var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, property, parameter);
            return lambda;
        }

        Expression<Func<Person, T>> GetLambdaSelector<T>(LambdaExpression expression)
        {
            return (Expression<Func<Person, T>>)expression;
        }
```

I'm stuck because I want to resolve the type (`DateTime`in the example) at runtime and not at compile time.

So how to call this method with type resolve at runtime:
`GetLambdaSelector<?>(lambda);` ?

Or maybe can I change the signature of `LambdaExpression GetLambdaExpression(string propertyName)` to `Expression<Func<Person, T>>` with reflection but I did not manage it for the moment. ?

Comment: You can't because then the `GroupBy` has an unknown type. You would need to call `GroupBy` with reflection also. Aside: if you are using LINQ-to-Objects (as opposed to SQL or EF) then you don't need an `Expression`, you can create a delegate straight off the property getter: `propertyInfo.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func...`

Comment: (Sticking `.AsQueryable()` on the end of something won't magically let it run on the database. Since you're using the `IEnumerable` version of `GroupBy`, that will always need to run locally)

Comment: @canton7 I now but it's to use with EF. That's why I queryabalize ;)

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is that using `.AsQueryable()` won't magically make EF run your grouping -- it will still be executed locally. Adding `.AsQueryable()` makes exactly **zero** difference here